# Enabling spring boot application logs and watch it in aws cloud watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to watch logs created by spring boot in cloud watch, so what should be the location of the log file, when I am entering the local machine's location in the cloud watch config file ec2 is not starting

this is what I am adding in config file

```json
{
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [{
                    "file_path": "/home/ec2-user/logs/test.log",
                    "log_group_name": "java-aws-rnd-logging",
                    "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}.log",
                    "timestamp_format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f",
                    "multi_line_start_pattern": "{timestamp_format}"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you install and configure the Cloudwatch Agent in your EC2 instance? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html

Comment: yes, I have done al the setup

Comment: In the configuration you should have specified the loggroup name and the name of the stream, if the stream name was not supplied then the instance ID is used.

Comment: I want to change aws default config to my config in which I want to put logs from file that is saved in local machine. Can you help ?

Comment: see I have added my config file details, is it oky ?

Answer (score 0):

Save your configuration file as `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json`[1] and run the agent with the command `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c file:configuration-file-path` [2]

Ref:

- [1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#Saving-Agent-Configuration-File
- [2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance-fleet.html#start-CloudWatch-Agent-EC2-fleet